# Indy HMAC-SHA1 generating unexpected values

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy, hmacsha1

I'm attempting to use a 3rd party service that uses OAuth 1.0a and requires HMAC-SHA1 for the signature. I wrote a working version in C# and went to try to move it over to Delphi XE2. I immediately noticed something was wrong, the server was rejecting my calls saying that my "Signature is invalid." This is my method for generating a signature:

```
function TOAuth1.GenerateSignature(signatureBase, key : string) : string;
var
  hmacSha1 : TIdHMACSHA1;
  keyBytes, textBytes, hashedBytes : TBytes;
begin
  if(AnsiCompareText(fSignMethod,'PLAINTEXT') = 0) then
  begin
    Result := key;
  end
  else if(AnsiCompareText(fSignMethod,'HMAC-SHA1') = 0) then
  begin
    hmacSha1 := TIdHMACSHA1.Create;
    SetLength(keyBytes,Length(key));
    Move(key[1],keyBytes[0],Length(key));
    hmacSha1.Key := keyBytes;
    SetLength(textBytes,Length(signatureBase));
    Move(signatureBase[1],textBytes[0],Length(signatureBase));
    hashedBytes := hmacSha1.HashValue(textBytes);
    Result := EncodeBase64(hashedBytes,Length(hashedBytes));
    keyBytes := nil;
    textBytes := nil;
    hashedBytes := nil;

    hmacSha1.Free;
    hmacSha1 := nil;
  end;
end;
```

I couldn't spot anything that looked wrong to me, so I grabbed a `signatureBase` and `key` from my C# tests

signatureBase: `POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fsign-in-with-twitter%252F%26oauth_consumer_key%3DcChZNFj6T5R0TigYB9yd1w%26oauth_nonce%3Dea9ec8429b68d6b77cd5600adbbb0456%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1318467427%26oauth_version%3D1.0`

key: `L8qq9PZyRg6ieKGEKhZolGC0vJWLw8iEJ88DRdyOg&`

Using these values in C#, I was given the signature `F1Li3tvehgcraF8DMJ7OyxO4w9Y=`, which was the expected value that Twitter gave me. However, in Delphi, I was given the signature `/kov410nJhE6PTlk0R8bjP7JQq4=`

In Delphi I called my function like this:

```
  signature := self.GenerateSignature('POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fsign-in-with-twitter%252F%26oauth_consumer_key%3DcChZNFj6T5R0TigYB9yd1w%26oauth_nonce%3Dea9ec8429b68d6b77cd5600adbbb0456%26oauth_signature_method'+'%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1318467427%26oauth_version%3D1.0','L8qq9PZyRg6ieKGEKhZolGC0vJWLw8iEJ88DRdyOg&');
  assert(AnsiCompareStr(signature,'F1Li3tvehgcraF8DMJ7OyxO4w9Y=') = 0,'Signature generated is invalid');
```

So my question would be this: Am I using the HMAC-SHA1 incorrectly? If so, what steps should I take to fix it? If not, then is the implementation of HMAC-SHA1 in Indy done incorrectly? If so, is there an easy to use (preferably free) unit that can handle it correctly? Or is there something else altogether wrong here?

Comment: In encryption, keys are not `strings`, they should be `binary` values (because string encoding can vary). When looking at the C# code here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh674475.aspx the `key` should be interpreted as Base64 string (`Convert.FromBase64String` call) to convert them to bytes. The `signatureBase` as ASCII string (just as Stijn answered) of which the bytes are used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the common Unicode string misconception. Since Delphi 2009, `string` maps to `UnicodeString`, encoded with UTF-16, and no longer to `AnsiString`. So,

```
Move(key[1],keyBytes[0],Length(key));
```

will probably only copy the first half of the string with 2 bytes per character. Use [`UTF8Encode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UTF8Encode) to convert the key to UTF8 first, and copy that into keyBytes.

Comment: @Stijn Are you sure it's UTF-8 rather than plain old ASCII?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, since the key is URL encoded with `%`'s you won't have anything higher than #127, so yes plain AnsiString should do fine.